# Django: The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache

I have deployed my Django project on UWSGI on Apache. I can go to any non-root URL, but cannot go to mydomain.com. I get this error:
[image: Requested URL /index.html]

My URL patterns include the root:

```
url(r'^$', views.TasksView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Do you know what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you fire up a runserver with debug turned on and look at the stack trace?

Comment: You requested `/index.html`, but your application does not know about that url.  It only knows about `/`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I added that and now Chrome tries to download a gzipped file.

Comment: We can't help without seeing the code.

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon, thanks for your help, I got past the original issue. Now, my browser is serving up a download.gz file instead of rendering the html.

Comment: If serving a gz file is an error (which you haven't said, but presumably it is), we can't figure out why that is happening unless you show us a lot more code.

Comment: @JohnGordon What would I put in urls.py to capture that?

I'm getting GET / => generated 84 bytes in 92 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 4 headers in 114 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "capture".  We need to see the code of `views.TasksView`.  Edit your question and include that code.

Comment: You said that my application does not know about the url `/index.html'. By 'capture', I meant add to my `urls.py` so that my application knows about that url.

Comment: Make another url pattern that is identical to the one you posted, except it will have `r'^index.html$'` instead of `r'^$'`.